# How to updating a Restfull api list in Django with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, python, html, angularjs, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make a simple invitation system, and i want to update a specific field "accepted" from false to true for every invite, when i click on accept button in a template. i'm a beginner in AngularJs

Restfull Api in the url /site/invitations/ :

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Vary: Accept
Content-Type: application/json

[
    {
        "id": 10,
        "user_from_name": "achref97",
        "accepted": false,
        "deleted": false,
        "user_from": 22,
        "user_to": 24,
    }
]
```

template.html :

```
<div class="col-lg-7 col-md-6 no-pd"  ng-app="isamm.demo" >
   <div class="main-ws-sec">
        <div class="posts-section">
            <div class="post-bar">
            <div class="job_descp" ng-controller="InvitationController">
            {% verbatim  %}
            <div ng-repeat="invite in invitations">
            <h3>pour {{invite.user_from}}</h3>

            <button ng-click="update()">accept</button>

</div>
{% endverbatim  %}


</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript :
As you can see i retrieve the list of invitations from /site/invitations/, then in the template i create a button with update() function, but i can't continue from there, any help?.

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('isamm.demo', []);




        app.controller('InvitationController', function ($scope,$http) {
            $scope.invitations= [];
            $http.get('/site/invitations/').then(function(response){
                $scope.invitations= response.data;

            });
            $scope.update = function (){
                // What to do here?
            };





            });






}());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.update = function (id){
    $scope.invitations.filter(invite => {
        if (id === invite.id) {
            invite.accepted = true;
        } 
    });
};
```

and pass invite.id to update method in markup